# $http.post cannot find issue

Tags: post, runtime-error, mean-stack

Good afternoon everyone.

I'm working on a school project to create an application using the MEAN stack, and I'm having issues with routing.
I'm using the login-and-register application found here as a base for my work : http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/12/09/mean-stack-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial
Basically, I am unable to post data that I get from a form I created to my database.
If I get the creation part to work, then I'll be able to continue working on my project. Here is the code :

**The Controller**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function Controller(UserService, NoteService, FlashService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.note = null;


        function createNote() {
            NoteService.Create(vm.note, vm.user)
                .then(function () {
                    FlashService.Success('Note created'); 
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    FlashService.Error(error);
                });
        }

        vm.createNote = createNote;

        function initController() {...}

        initController();
    }

    angular.module('app').controller('Home.IndexController', Controller);

    }());
```

And then we have the service I'm calling, NoteService

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function Service($http, $q) {
        var service = {};


        function Create(note, user) {
            return $http.post('/api/notes', note).then(handleSuccess, handleError);
        }

        service.Create = Create;

        return service;
    }

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('NoteService', Service);

}());
```

This is the $http.post function that doesn't work : /api/notes cannot be found (error 404 on browser console) I am sure my object note is getting at least to this request, because adding a console.log(note) just before returns what I want in the console.

On the server side, I have another controller for handling errors :

```
var noteService = require('services/notes.service');

//routes
router.post('/create', createNote);

module.exports = router;

function createNote(req, res) {

    noteService.create(req.body)
        .then(function () {
            res.sendStatus(200);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            res.status(400).send(err);
        });

}
```

the service on the server side to discuss with the data base :

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db(config.connectionString, { native_parser: true });
db.bind('notes');

var service = {};

service.create = create;

module.exports = service;

function create(noteParam, userParam) {...}
```

and my server.js file looks like this :

```
require('rootpath')();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({ secret: config.secret, resave: false, saveUninitialized: true }));

// use JWT auth to secure the api
app.use('/api', expressJwt({ secret: config.secret }).unless({ path: ['/api/users/authenticate', '/api/users/register'] }));

// routes
app.use('/login', require('./controllers/login.controller'));
app.use('/register', require('./controllers/register.controller'));
app.use('/app', require('./controllers/app.controller'));
app.use('/api/users', require('./controllers/api/users.controller'));
app.use('/api/notes', require('./controllers/api/notes.controller'));

// make '/app' default route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    return res.redirect('/app');
});

// start server
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server listening at http://' + server.address().address + ':' + server.address().port);
});
```

I thought this line in the server.js file : app.use('/api/notes', require('./controllers/api/notes.controller'))
would permit my post request to send my note object to the server side, to '/api/notes') but I'm not quite sure how all this works together.

I am hoping anyone can help me, even though the code I gave was lengthful.
I am just beginning with MEAN and have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in Advance for your answer.

Comment: Can you duplicate the problem with a smaller code-set?

Comment: I tried to reduce it. Everything that is left is related to the function createNote() that is not working for me !